# Require express in one file and use express.static in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How would I use express in one file, in other files that need to use the express package also. Currently I have a file server.js, that has the

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

I want to use express in my other files that are in different directories, how would I do this without doing a require?

Updated question

---

How would I pass 'var express = require('express');' to another file so that I can use express.static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `require` you can pass `app` like this:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var something = require('./something')(app);
```

something.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  // do something with app
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. But for line 3 in your code, did you mean to do `require('./something.js')(app);` And what is that second parameter of (app) after ('./something')

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to add`.js` when using require. The second parameter is the express instance `app` from line 2, which then gets passed to the other file. The other file exports a function which expects that parameter. There you can do anything with `app`, like for example define routes.

Comment: so then to use 'app' I would do: 'something.app.use();' in the other file

Comment: You can just do `app.use();` in both files

Comment: How would I pass the code in line one, when I require express? I am trying to use express.static in another js file but it keeps saying it undefined or not a function

Comment: and to use the function, I would do: something(); in app.js?

Comment: Yes, but you already do that by `require('./something')(app)`. [Here](https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/require-basics-in-node-js-8ab0591d03a#.t6k2r24ic) is an article that explains the basics of `require`

Answer (score 1):

You can use module.exports to assign app variable , which can be used imported/required my other file . Sample example like below

**a.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
module.exports.app = app;
```

**b.js**

```
var a = require('./a');
a.app.listen(3000,function(){
 console.log("Server Is up and running");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In nodeJs different files that we have in our application are treated as different module, so when we want to use them we export them and use them, here express is a package we are using so you can define it one file and export that file and require it in another file.
  use module.exports and require it another file.

Comment: Do you mean to export the instance of 'app' like how Sumeet has done above?

Comment: yes , and you can have your other middlewares and routes etc declared with that app variable and export it.